# Rails query .order trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Querying has never been my strong point. I'm trying to modify my current query to allow order by ASC/DESC.

For this, I have a model Activity that is extended to Share, Scan, Review, Redeem (accessible by Activity.type).

My current query is

```
results=Activity.select("*, count(*) as count").where(created_at: date_from..date_to).group(:user_id).having("count > 0").count("type='#{val}', count(*) #{desc/asc}")
```

Which gives me something like:

```
{2=>1, 3=>1, 1=>305, 111=>99, 110=>98, 109=>97, 108=>96, 107=>95, 106=>94, 105=>93,...
```

The problem here, is that the first 2 have `(type=#{val}).count` = 0. Meaning that they have Activity records under them, but they are of different type. Is there anyway to modify the query so that these .count=0 actually respect the ordering?

Otherwise as a work around I can add all of these to an array manually, then evaluate them last.

Edited: Updated to my current issue

Comment: You want to order by count and then by type?

Comment: Could you describe your needs in terms of the wanted output?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this:

```
results=Activity.select("*, count(*) as count")
.where(created_at: date_from..date_to).group(:user_id, :type)
.having("count > 0").order("type ASC, count(*) DESC")
```

Comment: Actually, this unfortunately is not fully ordering properly. when I do a count(*) DESC, it's putting records that have (type=a).count=0 first instead of at the back. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you reverse it, count(*) ASC

Comment: Oddly enough, it always keeps the ones with (type=a).count=0 at the top. I think the query I need will take too long to do and am simplifying the order to just be count(*) DESC. :)

Comment: Well it orders by type first, so type A would be the first regardless of the count. If you want to order by count first, move them around like this: ("count(*) DESC, type ASC")